# The thread has exited with code 1 (0x1)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-ce

The thread 'unsigned long __cdecl Open_Thread(void *)' (0x7380036) has exited with code 1 (0x1)

is this an error or thread executed successfully what doe sthe code indicates

Answer (score 9):

Exit code 0 is customarily used to signal successful termination. Exit code 1 would seem to indicate an error.

Only someone in possession of the specification of `Open_Thread` could be sure. That would be you.

Comment: How can I find why a thread is suddenly killed. I got this on my win32 app and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Debuggers do keep track of thread creation, termination, first-chance exceptions, DLL load events and so on. The message you saw is just diagnostics message, indicating that some thread has exited.